# Superwebsockets Subprotocols

Tags: .net, websocket

I'm working with [SuperWebSockets](http://superwebsocket.codeplex.com/), and the readme.txt for the jsoncommandassembly says:

1. Copy this project's output to working directory of SuperWebSocket's running container,
   SuperWebSocketService, SuperWebSocketWeb or your own container.

Well, maybe I'm like serious tired or who knows but what is considered the working container? I've placed it several places and the Assembly.Load causes an exception, file not found. Where should I place the jsoncommandassembly dll?

Sorry I'm being dumb.

Comment: I got it. Super tired. Thanks